# How to find documents with multiple conditions using mongo-driver/mongo

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query

While querying the below data, returned cursor is empty. while there is 100s of documents which satisfy the condition.

```
 {
  "_id": "5dd68c51a39809125944ffba",
  "status": "success",
  "balance": "0.000",
  "request_params": {
   "username": "test_user",
   "service_code": "MR"
 }
```

using below code

MongoDB driver  "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"

```
func saveLog(data Log) bool {
    mongo, err := openMongo()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        fmt.Println("Connection failed")
        return false
    } else {
        LogCollection := mongo.Database(LogDb).Collection(CollectionLog)
        insertedApi, err := LogCollection.InsertOne(context.TODO(), data)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            fmt.Println("Insert failed")
            return false
        } else {
            log.Println(insertedApi.InsertedID)
            return true
        }
    }
}

func parseLog() {
    db, err := openMongo()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        fmt.Println("Connection failed")
        return
    } else {
        logCollection := db.Database(LogDb).Collection(CollectionLog)
        var results [] *Log
        find := bson.D{{"status","success"},{"request_params",bson.D{{"username","test_user"}}}}
        fmt.Println(find)
        cur, err := logCollection.Find(context.TODO(), find)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }else {
            for cur.Next(context.TODO()) {
                var elem Log
                err := cur.Decode(&elem)
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("Parse error : ",err)
                }
                fmt.Println("Log : ",elem)
                results = append(results, &elem)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Log write

```
saveLog(Log{"success","0.000",RequestParams{"test_user","MR"}})
```

Log read

```
parseLog()
```

Log struct

```
type Log struct {
    Status string `bson:"status"`
    Balance string `bson:"balance"`
    RequestParams RequestParams `bson:"request_params"`
}
type RequestParams struct {
    Username string `bson:"username"`
    ServiceCode     string `bson:"service_code"`
}
```

MongoDB data

[image: MongoDB data]

status only is returning whole 8k documents

```
bson.D{{"status","success"}}
```

Isn't  collection.Find() function the right one for it.

Shell command is returning documents correctly

```
db.log.find({"status":"success","request_params.username":"test_user"}).limit(10).pretty()
```

Comment: Is this the program you're running? It should give a syntax error in: `"request_params",bson.D{{"username","test_user"},"service_code": "MR"}`, the service_code part.

Comment: @BurakSerdar No syntax error or any other, program runs smoothly.

Comment: Here's the part that's troubling: `bson.D{{"username","test_user"},"service_code": "MR"}` It should be `bson.D{{"username","test_user"},{"service_code", "MR"}}

Comment: Sorry that was a copy-paste mistake when I pasted code here still not working. updated question

Comment: Try: `bson.M{"status":"success","request_params":bson.D{{"username","test_user"},{"service_code","MR"}}}`

Comment: @rafidkotta could you elaborate what do you mean by getting nothing ? As in, your print statement for `elem` does not print anything ? Using your example document, and your example code, I'm unable to reproduce the issue that you're seeing.

Comment: @BurakSerdar still empty cursor

Comment: @WanBachtiar I am getting an empty cursor while there is 100s of docs satisfying the condition. - updated in question

Comment: i don't understand how the driver is supposed to decode to `*interface{}`. OP code is dubious

Comment: @rafidkotta which version of the driver are you using ? Also, is the code above the code that you're testing with ? Could you try copying a handful of documents (5-10) to a test collection and check with the code above ?

Comment: @WanBachtiar document has other data other than passed data. When i pass whole data it's returning the document but i can't pass the that. Updated the question with more info, Thanks

Comment: @rafidkotta the way you're searching for the `request_params` is likely the culprit. Can you try this: `bson.M{"status":"success","request_params.username":"testuser","request_params.service_code":"MR"}` Note it is bson.M, not bson.D. With bson.D, order matters.

Comment: @BurakSerdar  Yes I saw the your answer when I came to reply Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is because of the query filter. There is a difference between the following queries:

```
// Query A: {"status": "success", "request_params": {"username":"test_user"}}
find := bson.D{{"status","success"},{"request_params",bson.D{{"username","test_user"}}}}

// Query B: {"status": "success", "request_params.username":"test_user"}
find := bson.D{{"status","success"},{"request_params.username","test_user"}}
```

Query A means that you would like to match an exact document of `request_params` where the value object exactly equal to `{"username":"test_user"}`. None of the documents in your collection matches this criteria. The documents also contains `{"service_code":"MR"}`. While query B uses [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation), which means that you would like to match `request_params` field where it *contains* a value of `{"username":"test_user"}`.

See also [Query on Nested Field](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#query-on-nested-field) for more information.